# Problem with matplotlib savefig function in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am new in using Python and I'm using PyCharm as the working environment. I am having problems using the savefig function inside a double for-loop with the following code:

```
for i in range(len(Name1)):
    for j in range(len(Name2)):
        fig2 = plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(Data.loc[:, Name2[j]], Data.loc[:, Name1[i]], s=1.5)
        plt.xlabel( Name2[j])
        plt.ylabel(Labels[i] + Units[i] )
        plt.savefig('Figures/' + KPI[i] + variations[j] +'.pdf', bbox_inches="tight")
        fig2.show()
```

where `Name1` and `Name2` are just lists of different filenames.

The error I get is the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 729, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2180, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2091, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 2496, in print_pdf
    file = PdfFile(filename, metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 432, in __init__
    fh, opened = cbook.to_filehandle(filename, "wb", return_opened=True)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 432, in to_filehandle
    fh = open(fname, flag, encoding=encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Figures/corr_eff_enmp.pdf'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is recommended that you copy-paste the error instead of posting an image. Also, your image does not contain the entire error.

Comment: `.pdf'code` should be supported by `plt.savefig`

Comment: @C_Z_ Yes sorry, it is my first time posting. The entire error is now in OP.

Comment: Hi, you're almost there. There should also be more details on the error above and below the traceback

Comment: Not sure if this is in your actual code, but is seems like there is a comma after the close bracket on plt.savefig().

Comment: @C_Z_ Ah yes, sorry. It should be there now.

Comment: @noahjillson That was a mistake in the post, not a part of the code. Thanks :)

Comment: Does the `Figures` directory exist where it is expected to?

Comment: What is the working directory when you run this python code? Where is this `Figures` directory that you are trying to write to?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]. This doesn't need to be the full code you are actually working on, just the pieces that are important for what you are asking about while still not producing other errors that get in the way. For example, you can hard code the path, instead of relying on variables that aren't declared. You can also draw a simple box or line to save to the file instead of the full figure you likely want instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have edited the OP so that it includes the double for-loop as well, hope it is more clear now. 
Regarding Figures, I just meant for it to be a string so the name of each saved image starts with Figures.

Comment: @Python_beginner See the answer bellow, I believe using the full path should fix your error.

Comment: Your code still contains several undeclared variables that cause errors other than the one you are asking about. Besides, the for loops are unimportant to the error that you are seeing. Please read the link in my previous comment. The important thing here is that we can copy/paste your code then run it and get the exact same error you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not using the full path to the `/Figures` folder. If the Figures folder is not nested inside where your python files are, then this is the root of the error. I would use the full path to said folder. Linked bellow are ways to find the full path to your folder for both Windows and Mac https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/show-full-folder-path-file-explorer. https://osxdaily.com/2013/06/19/copy-file-folder-path-mac-os-x/.